# Annotate ggplot2 facets with number of observations per facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a facet_wrap plot with ggplot2 with different annotations in each plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050610/creating-a-facet-wrap-plot-with-ggplot2-with-different-annotations-in-each-plot)
>   [Add text to a faceted plot in ggplot2 with dates on X axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458349/add-text-to-a-faceted-plot-in-ggplot2-with-dates-on-x-axis)

Occasionally when faceting data in ggplot, I think it would be nice to annotate each facet with the number of observations that fell into each facet. This is particularly important when faceting may result in relatively few observations per facet.

What would be the best / simplest way to add an "n=X" to each facet of this plot?

```
require(ggplot2)
mms <- data.frame(deliciousness = rnorm(100),
                  type=sample(as.factor(c("peanut", "regular")), 100, replace=TRUE),
                  color=sample(as.factor(c("red", "green", "yellow", "brown")), 100, replace=TRUE))


plot <- ggplot(data=mms, aes(x=deliciousness)) + geom_density() + facet_grid(type ~ color)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050610/creating-a-facet-wrap-plot-with-ggplot2-with-different-annotations-in-each-plot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458349/add-text-to-a-faceted-plot-in-ggplot2-with-dates-on-x-axis

Comment: up-voted for a including the image and reproducible data (cf. "creating a facet_wrap...")

Answer (score 51):

It looks like this has been asked before, and I failed initially to see how they connected. I'm answering this here, but leaving it as not accepted in case someone has something more elegant. Also, the n = foo is a common enough case, that hopefully someone will get some use out of this question even though it's a bit duplicative.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)
mms <- data.frame(deliciousness = rnorm(100),
                  type=sample(as.factor(c("peanut", "regular")), 
                              100, replace=TRUE),
                  color=sample(as.factor(c("red", "green", "yellow", "brown")), 
                              100, replace=TRUE))


mms.cor <- ddply(.data=mms, 
                 .(type, color), 
                 summarize, 
                 n=paste("n =", length(deliciousness)))

plot <- ggplot(data=mms, aes(x=deliciousness)) + 
          geom_density() + 
          facet_grid(type ~ color) + 
          geom_text(data=mms.cor, aes(x=1.8, y=5, label=n), 
                    colour="black", inherit.aes=FALSE, parse=FALSE)

plot
```

[image: The output]

Comment: Thanks - this provided an answer that I hadn't found elsewhere

Comment: Even if technically a duplicate, this example has the merit of being simpler and is going to the core of the solution. The OP's title is clearer as well imho.

Comment: Got a bit of a simpler solution - avoids having to define `mms.cor`. Within `geom_text`, define the data as `data = plyr::count(mms, vars = c("deliciousness"))`. Caveat being I've only tested this with facets for only one variable, not two.

Comment: Thanks, helpful Q&A indeed!
Inspired by @spops comment, I found a solution that would work on this data frame, facetting on two variables, without the need for `mms.cor`:

`geom_text(data=plyr::count(mms, vars = c("type","color")), aes(x=1.8, y=5, label=paste0("N=",freq)), colour="black", inherit.aes=FALSE, parse=FALSE)`