# R: ggplot2, how to annotate summary statistics on each panel of a panel plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How would I add a text annotation (eg. sd = sd_value) of the standard deviation in each panel of the following plot using ggplot2 in R?

```
library(datasets)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp)) + 
        geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1) + 
        geom_density() + 
        facet_grid(. ~ cyl) + 
        theme_bw()
```

I'd post an image of the plot, but I don't have enough rep.

I think "geom_text" or "annotate" might be useful but I'm not sure quite sure how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Annotate ggplot2 facets with number of observations per facet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239843/annotate-ggplot2-facets-with-number-of-observations-per-facet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to vary the text label in each facet, you will want to use `geom_text`. If you want the same text to appear in each facet, you can use `annotate`.

```
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl)

mylabels <- data.frame(
  cyl = c(4, 6, 8), 
  label = c("first label", "second label different", "and another")
)

p + geom_text(x = 200, y = 0.75, aes(label = label), data = mylabels)

### compare that to this way with annotate

p + annotate("text", x = 200, y = 0.75, label = "same label everywhere")
```

Now, if you really want standard deviation by `cyl` in this example, I'd probably use `dplyr` to do the calculation first and then complete this with `geom_text` like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
    
df.sd.hp <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(hp.sd = round(sd(hp), 2))
    
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +
  geom_text(
    data = df.sd.hp, 
    aes(label = paste0("SD: ", hp.sd))
    x = 200, y = 0.75
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. The last example with geom_text is exactly what I was looking for. I'm still getting used to ggplot2; is there a way to do the same thing with the stat_ family of functions in ggplot2 for common statistical calculations without having to use dplyr first?

Comment: Also, how could I include greek letters (eg. sigma) and/or latex (eg. \sigma^2) in the text part of the label?

Comment: You can use expression() for math notation.

Comment: Using parse=T in geom_text solved it for me. So for the above example the following works: geom_text(x = 200, y = 0.75, 
            aes(label = paste0("sigma ==", hp.sd)), 
            data = df.sd.hp,
            parse=T)

Comment: Now, how could multiple lines be included in the label to include, say, mean and standard deviation?

Comment: @adatum For multiple lines you could follow the `df.sd.hp` with multiple variables such as `...summarise(hp.sd = round(sd(hp), 2), hp.mean = round(mean(hp), 2))` and then do something like `paste0("SD: ", hp.sd, "\nMean: ", hp.mean, ...`

Comment: The `\n` doesn't seem to work here. For an easy example without extra calculation: `paste0("SD: ", hp.sd, "\nVar: ", hp.sd^2)` doesn't print anything after `hp.sd` if parse=T. It works if parse=F.

Comment: Please remove the space in `my labels`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the appearance of the graph when the statistic appears within the facet label itself. I made the following script, which allows the choice of displaying the **standard deviation**, **mean** or **count**. Essentially it calculates the summary statistic then merges this with the name so that you have the format *CATEGORY (SUMMARY STAT = VALUE)*.

```
   #' Function will update the name with the statistic of your choice
AddNameStat <- function(df, category, count_col, stat = c("sd","mean","count"), dp= 0){

  # Create temporary data frame for analysis
  temp <- data.frame(ref = df[[category]], comp = df[[count_col]])

  # Aggregate the variables and calculate statistics
  agg_stats <- plyr::ddply(temp, .(ref), summarize,
                           sd = sd(comp),
                           mean = mean(comp),
                           count = length(comp))

  # Dictionary used to replace stat name with correct symbol for plot
  labelName <- mapvalues(stat, from=c("sd","mean","count"), to=c("\u03C3", "x", "n"))

  # Updates the name based on the selected variable
  agg_stats$join <- paste0(agg_stats$ref, " \n (", labelName," = ",
                           round(agg_stats[[stat]], dp), ")")

  # Map the names
  name_map <- setNames(agg_stats$join, as.factor(agg_stats$ref))
  return(name_map[as.character(df[[category]])])
}
```

Using this script with your original question:

```
library(datasets)
data(mtcars)

# Update the variable name
mtcars$cyl  <- AddNameStat(mtcars, "cyl", "hp", stat = "sd")

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The script should be easy to alter to include other summary statistics. I am also sure it could be rewritten in parts to make it a bit cleaner!

Comment: Nice formatting; I like it. Improvements could include adding units, and allowing multiple statistics.