# Annotate ggplot boxplot facets with number of observations per bar/group

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I already looked through other questions like these ([Annotate ggplot2 facets with number of observations per facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239843/annotate-ggplot2-facets-with-number-of-observations-per-facet)), but didn't find the answer for carrying out an annotation of the single bars of a boxplot with facets.

Here's my sample code for creating the boxplot:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)
mms <- data.frame(deliciousness = rnorm(100),
                  type=sample(as.factor(c("peanut", "regular")), 
                              100, replace=TRUE),
                  color=sample(as.factor(c("red", "green", "yellow", "brown")), 
                               100, replace=TRUE))

ggplot(mms, aes(x=type, y=deliciousness, fill=type)) + 
   geom_boxplot(notch=TRUE)+
   facet_wrap(~ color,nrow=3, scales = "free")+
   xlab("")+
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("coral1", "lightcyan1", "olivedrab1"))+
   theme(legend.position="none")
```

And here the corresponding plot:

[image]

Now I want to annotate individually for each facet of the color the number of observations per group (peanut/regular), as shown in my drawing:

[image]

What I already did, was summarizing the number of observations with dpyr per color and per group (peanut/regular) with this code:

```
 mms.cor <- ddply(.data=mms, 
                  .(type,color), 
                  summarize, 
                  n=paste("n =", length(deliciousness)))
```

However, I do not know how to add this summary of the data to the ggplot. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach using `dplyr` and `ggplot2`. You can build the label with `mutate()` and then format to have only one value based on max value of `deliciousness`. After that `geom_text()` can enable the text as you want. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Data
mms <- data.frame(deliciousness = rnorm(100),
                  type=sample(as.factor(c("peanut", "regular")), 
                              100, replace=TRUE),
                  color=sample(as.factor(c("red", "green", "yellow", "brown")), 
                               100, replace=TRUE))
#Plot
mms %>% group_by(color,type) %>% mutate(N=n()) %>%
  mutate(N=ifelse(deliciousness==max(deliciousness,na.rm=T),paste0('n=',N),NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=type, y=deliciousness, fill=type,label=N)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch=TRUE)+
  geom_text(fontface='bold')+
  facet_wrap(~ color,nrow=3, scales = "free")+
  xlab("")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("coral1", "lightcyan1", "olivedrab1"))+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The explanation seems good. However, when I run the code, I get the following error: Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: @Olympia Try loading `dplyr` and `ggplot2` in a new fresh session and test initially with the data you shared. It looks like you do not have the package loaded

Comment: @Olympia Fantastic! It is also a great question :)

Comment: thanks, if you liked the question, can you vote it up? :-)