# How to display number of cases per group in a stacked bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to produce a stacked bar plot that has the fill color defined by a variable and also shows the number of cases represented by each of the filled sections.

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

data(mpg)

ggplot(mpg,aes(manufacturer))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "count",aes(fill=drv))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(text = element_text(size=20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, 
                                   vjust = 0.5))
```

which produces [image: this image].

Here is a paired-down version of what I would like to produce programmatically:

[image], where the

**n=...**

are centered on each groups filled section and display the number of cases per group (drv) in each category (manufacturer).

Additionally, I have tried (unsuccessfully) incorporating code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64898257/annotate-ggplot-boxplot-facets-with-number-of-observations-per-bar-group) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620262/showing-percentage-in-bars-in-ggplot), which seem close to what I want, but when I incorporate the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620262/showing-percentage-in-bars-in-ggplot) the following error is thrown:

> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?

I am not sure why this error is thrown because I do define stat="count" in the geom_bar() function call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `position_fill(vjust = 0.5)` and label with `after_stat(count)`:

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(manufacturer, fill = drv)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "count")+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("n=", after_stat(count))), stat='count', position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Note: semi-hidden plotting components like `..count..` are considered deprecated. This can be replaced in your code with the better documented `after_stat(count)`.

Comment: On a _horizontal_ stacked bars the counts are reversed : what's on the left should be on the right and vice versa. Any help?

Comment: try `rev`, if it does not work, you can still do a new question